# Ul tag not taking full width on bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have used Bootstrap on my WordPress site, I used the bootstrap grid to divide the contents of the page into two, one of them is having a card which acts like a nav menu.

The problem is the `<ul>` element is not taking full width.

In the left side of the site, there are two items named "introduction", which is not taking full width.

I tried

```
display:inline;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 0px;
```

none of them work.

Comment: The link given for this question no longer matches up to the description given. This question therefore no longer has a [mcve] and would be best put on hold until it can be repaired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website has `margin: 0 0 1.5em 3em;` applied to all `ul` and `ol` elements. You might want to figure out where that's coming from and remove it. Or you could just override it by adding this to your stylesheet:

```
ul, ol {
  margin: 0
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: when I used ul, ol {
  margin: 0
}

it changed margin in the whole site so I used

.card ul {
 margin:0;
}

which worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In card `> .list-group` give

```
margin: 0;
```